# How can I make jquery script that will hide table when table is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some CSV to html generator. It generates CSV data to html table. For example

```
 <table><tbody><tr><th>Name 1</th><th>Name 2</th></tr>
 <tr><td>123</td><td>123</td></tr>
 </tbody></table>
```

Sometimes there is no data to generate. Then table looks like this (it shows only headers)

```
 <table><tbody><tr><th>Name 1</th><th>Name 2</th></tr>
 </tbody></table>
```

In this case I want to show instead of table some text. Lets say:

```
 <h1>There is no data man!</h1>
 <p>Contact to Us</p>
```

How I can do this?

Comment: .... you should consider to share some JS, at least your function that returns your table, and the way it's invoked....

Comment: It should be done the code which is generating the table

Comment: How you generate the data to display inside a table

Comment: `$('table').filter(function(){$(this).find('tr').length==1}).hide()` OR `$('table').filter(function(){$(this).find('tr').length==1}).replaceWith('<h1>There is no data man!</h1><p>Contact to Us</p>')`

Comment: How you display your table data ? using Mysql or anything else?

Comment: show code which generate csv to html

Comment: Your header have to be inside <thead> and not in <tbody>

Answer (score 0):

You can check number of lines in the table and change html if it's empty.

Code is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rowCount = $('tbody > tr').length;

    if(rowCount > 1 ){ // check one more after header 
      $('table').replaceWith(" <h1>There is no data man!</h1><p>Contact to Us</p>")
    }
})
```

Edit: after Pimskie comment, I changed code.

Here is a working example https://plnkr.co/edit/CSss8LqJ0uC5pbkoPrAu?p=preview

Comment: This hides the table, and add a message. Isn't the message hidden too?

Comment: It will be append after. I think it will be visible

Answer (score 0):

try this check

```js
   $('table').each(function(){
 var element = $(this).find('tbody tr:nth-child(2)').length;
if (element == 0) {
$(this).empty();
$(this).append(" <h1>There is no data man!</h1><p>Contact to Us</p>")
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table><tbody><tr><th>Name 1</th><th>Name 2</th></tr>

 </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `th` inside a `thead`. After that, a simple vanillaJS:

```
var table = document.querySelector('table');
var rows = document.querySelector('tbody > tr');

if (rows.length === 0) {
    table.parentNode.innerHTML = '<h1>There is no data man!</h1><p>Contact to Us</p>';
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h8y1jLca/3/

**edit**

if you can't place the `th`'s in a `thead` for some reason, this also works:
https://jsfiddle.net/h8y1jLca/4/

Answer (score -1):

```js
var tbody = $("#incidents tbody");

if (tbody.children().length == 0) {
alert('There is no data man! Contact us');
   
}
else
{
alert('Table contains some data');
}
```

```css
Try This One
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<table id="incidents">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>one</td></tr>
        <tr><td>two</td></tr>
        <tr><td>three</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```